# Transposing a Pandas DataFrame Without Aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a multi-columned dataframe which holds several numerical values that are the same. It looks like the following:

```
       A   B   C   D
0      1   1   10  1
1      1   1   20  2
2      1   5   30  3
3      2   2   40  4
4      2   3   50  5
```

This is great, however, I need to make A the index and B the column. The problem is that the column is aggregated and is averaged for every identical value of B.

```
df = DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2],
                'B':[1,1,5,2,3],
                'C':[10,20,30,40,50],
                'D':[1,2,3,4,5]})

transposed_df = df.pivot_table(index=['A'], columns=['B'])
```

Instead of keeping 10 and 20 across B1, it averages the two to 15.

```
      C                      D
B     1     2     3     5    1    2    3    5
A
1  15.0   NaN   NaN  30.0  1.5  NaN  NaN  3.0
2   NaN  40.0  50.0   NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0  NaN
```

Is there any way I can Keep column B the same and display every value of C and D using Pandas, or am I better off writing my own function to do this? Also, it is very important that the index and column stay the same because only one of each number can exist.

EDIT: This is the desired output. I understand that this exact layout probably isn't possible, but it shows that 10 and 20 need to both be in column 1 and index 1.

```
      C                          D
B     1        2     3     5     1        2    3    5
A
1  10.0,20.0  NaN   NaN    30.0  1.0,2.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  NaN        40.0  50.0   NaN   NaN      4.0  5.0  NaN
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: pivot_table uses mean as the default aggfunc in case it encounters duplicate entries. Thats what is happening here. You can choose another aggfunc

Comment: @user3483203 posted the desired output. Sorry for not having it before.

Comment: @BryceBooze try `df.astype(str).pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', aggfunc=','.join)`

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks, this produces exactly what I asked for. The only thing is that I can't figure out how to cast this back to a numeric number because I need to convert it to a numpy array. I know this is out of the scope of the question, but if you have any ideas that would be great.

Comment: you could also make sure you include a unique index to avoid this problem- like this df.reset_index().pivot_table(index = ['index', 'A'], columns = ['B']) then you can cast it to your array

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks for all your help! This got me exactly what I need